# OS X detect file open event

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I am building an OS X app, and in it I need to be able to detect if any file is opened from ANY app on the Mac. For example, let's say somebody Opens Photoshop and then clicks on File->New, I need to be able to detect this event in my app. Or if somebody double clicks on a file in Finder and opens it, I need to be able to detect it.

Can somebody please help me to get started with this?

Comment: You can read filesystem events, but this will include every file that is opened by every program, whether or not the program is an application (it could be a background process) and whether the file is a document, a preferences file, a cache file, or whatever. It will be extremely noisy.

Comment: File->New doesn't open a file. It becomes a file when it's saved.

Comment: There's no notification posted in this case.  You'd either have to inject custom code into each application separately, I imagine.

Comment: Dietrich: Can you use FSEvents to watch for reads?  AFAIK, they'll only tell you when a file is modified.